# Windows 10 IoT Dual Boot

Tags: software-installation, noobs, windows-iot

I have a new Raspberry Pi 2 Model B ARMv7 (with blank 64GB SDcard), and would like to install [Windows 10 IoT Core](http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/Downloads.htm). I know it's supported for this hardware.

What I'd like to do though, is have the ability to **dual-boot** Windows 10 IoT with another OS, such as Raspbian.

All the instructions I've found are for installing **only** Windows on the Pi. Or, installing something like NOOBS with multiple Linux-like OSes. Is this possible, and if so, how?

*(I have plenty of experience dual-booting Windows and Linux on desktop hardware ... noobie to RPi, though)*

Comment: Can't you make your own NOOBS install with IOT and Raspbian for instance? (Not looking into IOT so I don't know for sure but it seems logical)

Comment: @Havnar, I don't know. That's my question :)

Comment: download the lastest version of noobs from the raspberry pi website. copy the contents of that zip file to your empty sd card. make sure you hook the raspi up to the internet with a ethernet cable, this is important to be able to download and install anything other than rasbian. plug the power cable to raspberry for and let it boot up. here is where you will select which os's to install. you can choose more than one and everytime you turn on your raspi you will be given the choice of which os you would like to use. I current use this method to switch between openelec and rasbian. Windows 10 Io

Comment: Just tested it the noobs way. It does work. I have Rasbian, openelec, and win 10 iot all on the same sd card

Answer (score 2):

From the currently running OS; modify `/boot/config.txt` and issue a reboot. The `kernel=..` option modifies which OS to load.

*Update with instructions:*
I'm guessing a bit here, haven't run Win myself. But I would be surprised if this didn't work:

1. Install Linux first and copy `/boot/kernel7.img` to a USB stick.
2. Install Windows.
3. Copy `kernel7.img` from USB stick to `/boot/linux7.img` (from inside Windows)
4. Edit `/boot/config.txt`, add argument `kernel=linux7.img`
5. Reboot. Hopefully you get Linux now.
6. To boot Windows, remove the `kernel=` from /boot/config.txt  and reboot again.

Hope it works...

Comment: There is no running OS, yet. It's a clean system. Can you expand on this a little? Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some details.

Comment: So, is `config.txt` the settings file for a proper *bootloader*? Editing a file and then rebooting isn't quite what I'd envisioned by *dual booting*. I was hoping that on device startup, there would be a menu that allowed me to choose between Windows and Raspbian. Is that not how it works on Pis? Also, do I need to layout out an **extra** partition for Windows when I first install Raspbian?

Comment: Yes `config.txt` belongs to the bootloader. A boot menu might be possible with NOOBS but I think only Linux is supported (correct me if I'm wrong). Yes you likely need separate partitions for Win and Linux.

Comment: There is [berryboot](http://www.berryterminal.com/doku.php/berryboot) so in  theory this may be possible, but I notice the files in the current download of the pi version have not changed in 1.5 years (which is ungood, since the included, required firmware inside should have).  Also, Windows is proprietary and there are likely some awkward hurdles no one will want to bother with (MS certainly will not do it) -- so "possible" in this case thus means in theory *only*.

Comment: @goldilocks, doesn't [this link](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/berryboot/berryboot-20150916-pi2-only.zip) suggest that they do have a new berryboot for the new Pi 2 B hardware? (Sep 16 2015) Or am I being fooled by the name of the file, versus something older *inside* the .zip file?

Comment: Yeah I didn't see that.  In fact you can easily update the firmware and such yourself anyway, so there is no need for them to stay in lockstep with their releases that way.  I am probably being a bit cynical about the possibilities WRT to windows as well -- someone just has to put work into it, which may happen eventually.

Comment: I don't think berryboot will work, since  it boots to the menu, and on selecting the image you want, it mounts it and effectively does a chroot - the kernel that boots and shows the berryboot menu is the one that also runs your linux installation.

Answer (score -1):

Have two SD cards, one Windows 10 IoT, the other Raspbian. Just swap SD card to swap OS.

Comment: The installation will be a little hard to access, physically. Do you think this is the **only** way to do it?

Comment: This is the most straightforward thing I've seen so far. Take my upvote.

Comment: This is not an answer the OP's question, as far as I can deduct.